# Add Context Menu to a dialogue in e4 rcp

Tags: rcp, e4

I want to add a context menu to a dialogue. I want it in such a way that when clicked anywhere where it is empty a deafaul context menu appears. I have seen example of context menu added to table and tree but not a dialogue as a whole any snippets or examples will  be greatly appreciated.

This is what I have tried.

```
import org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager;

@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {

    Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(4, false);
    layout.marginRight = 5;
    layout.marginLeft = 10;
    container.setLayout(layout);

    MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager();
    menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
    menuMgr.add(new Action("New Thing") {

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see org.eclipse.jface.action.Action#run()
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("came in options");
        }
    });

    parent.setMenu(menuMgr.createContextMenu(parent));
    productListTreeCheckBox(parent);
    return super.createDialogArea(parent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the menu in a similar way to the table/tree menu, but using to top level `Composite` for the dialog. Using a menu manager that might be something like:

```
Control topLevelComposite = ... get top level composite

MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager();
menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);

menuMgr.addMenuListener(... you menu listener....);

final Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(topLevelComposite);

topLevelComposite.setMenu(menu);
```

You will then have to call `setMenu` on every `Composite` and control in the dialog which you want to use this menu. You can just use:

```
control.setMenu(parent.getMenu());
```

for this (as long as you do it on everything starting from the children of `topLevelComposite`).

Comment: either I am doing it wrong or I am touching wrong component. I will put my code snippet and that might tell what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Also swapped parent with container did not work.Similar snippets works for showing context menu inside a table.

Comment: You have to call `setMenu` on every Composite and Control you create in the dialog.

Comment: parent.setMenu(menuMgr.createContextMenu(parent));
is this not what you mean by setmenu?

Comment: You use that on the top level composite and the other call on all the children